# Not able to get rid of Navbar item top/bottom margin?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm new with Bootstrap 4 and SASS. I've been struggling to learn how to make changes but have been able get a couple done. However, one of them I can't seem to figure out is the margin or padding at the top and bottom of the navbar item.

Here is what I've done. On a new MVC project I installed Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap.sass. I then created a new _custom-variables and copied the _variables content into it so that I can make some changes. I then created a _my-theme.scss file and imported all of them into my site.scss like this.

```
@import "scss/_custom-variables.scss";
@import "scss/_bootstrap.scss";
@import "scss/_my-theme.scss";
```

I was finally able to figure out how to change the background color of the navbar by creating a variable for my color and applying it to the _custom-variables and changing the link text to white:

```
$main-color: #0078D2;

// Navbar links
$navbar-default-link-color: #fff !default;
$navbar-default-link-hover-color: #fff !default;
$navbar-default-link-hover-bg: darken($main-color, 6.5%) !default;
```

I also had to set the following in the _my-theme.css to actually change the text color to white. I've watched some videos and I know it has to do with specifcicity but I still haven't really got my head wrapped around it. Based on a video I watched, what I did was inspect the link and found the properties that I just copied straight in to the _my-theme.scss.

This is what I had to add to the _my-theme.scss to get the text white.

```
.navbar-dark 
.navbar-nav 
.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{
    color: #fff;
}
```

However, there is still some padding or margin at the top each link that I would like to get rid of. You can see that I tried setting the `margin-top: 0px` and `margin-bottom: 0px` but that didn't work, neither did setting padding to 0px.

I also tried finding the setting in dev tools in Chrome but couldn't find what it is that is setting this.

This is my navbar layout:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top rounded-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

[image]

How can I remove this spacing and make the dark blue take the whole height of the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `navbar` class contains internal padding. If you want to remove the top and bottom padding, just add this CSS:

```
.navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming to just put this in the _my-theme file? No setting in the _variables file?

Comment: Yes that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The space is padding, and not margins. Use the `py-0` utility class to remove the padding from the navbar. And then add padding back to the `nav-link` to maintain the original height:

https://www.codeply.com/go/roU5MIf724

```
.navbar-dark 
.navbar-nav 
.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top rounded-0 py-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test this out as well. Didn't think about using the py-0 setting.

Comment: Both of these would work for different scenarios. This code would work when targeting just the specific settings such as navbar-dark and not affect the navbar-light. However it you want to universally remove the padding then the code from @DavidG would work a little more. Thanks for the answer!